# Unexpected token var s = await Database

Tags: javascript, async-await

When I try to run the following

```
'use strict'

const Database = use('Database')

class HomeController {


  index({equest,view}){

    var s = await Database
       .table('users')
       .first()

    return view.render("home",{s});

  }

}

module.exports = HomeController
```

It fives me this error, I think i traced it down that it does not like the `await` bit.

```
Unexpected token var s = await Database
```

Has anybody seen an issue like that?

Comment: Which version of Node.js are you using? Are you using Babel?

Comment: v8.9.1 and no, I thought await ships with it?

Comment: @jfriend00 `index` is a class method, and `{equest,view}` is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).